# Is it possible to create a unique ID for repeatedly measuring classes in a time-series?

Tags: pandas, time-series, repeat, unique-index

I have a csv file with a 24h time series containing measurements from 7 different valves (`solenoid vales`) that change every 10 min (valve 1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and than start with 1 again). I want to assign a unique `Measurement ID` to each time a valve measures (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13...) so that I can in an subsequent step extract the last 10 seconds (=lines) of each measurement interval.

Is this theoretical possible with pandas? I unsuccessfully tried to find a function that I could apply.

I have extracted this from my pandas dataframe `df`

```
df=pd.read_csv(file)


Out[61]: 
                DATE_TIME  solenoid_valves       N2O        CH4  CO2_ppm
0     10/08/2016 12:04:56         7.000000  0.272953   1.810904      NaN
....
8740  10/08/2016 14:30:36         2.000000  0.349828  29.527575   352.32
8741  10/08/2016 14:30:37              NaN       NaN        NaN   352.61
8742  10/08/2016 14:30:38         2.000000  0.349729  29.508612   352.12
8743  10/08/2016 14:30:39         2.000000  0.349655  29.501180   352.88
8744  10/08/2016 14:30:40         2.200969  0.349388  29.492402   353.16
8745  10/08/2016 14:30:41         2.600484  0.347622  29.483979   352.44
8746  10/08/2016 14:30:42         3.000000  0.341632  29.476394   352.96
...
56512   11/08/2016 3:46:48         3.000000  0.300992  8.988894   420.42
56513   11/08/2016 3:46:49         3.000000  0.304847  8.990150   420.60
56514   11/08/2016 3:46:50         3.143836  0.302620  8.991343   420.89
56515   11/08/2016 3:46:51         4.000000  0.295150  8.992416   421.90
56516   11/08/2016 3:46:52         4.000000  0.286783  8.993618   421.90
56517   11/08/2016 3:46:53         4.000000  0.285636  8.994677   421.57
56518   11/08/2016 3:46:54              NaN       NaN       NaN   422.47
56519   11/08/2016 3:46:55         4.000000  0.276346  8.993526   422.75
56520   11/08/2016 3:46:56         4.000000  0.277580  8.992645   423.02
```

I identified the following challenges:

- When the valve switches (see line 8744,8745 or 56514) one or more valve numbers tend to have decimal numbers.  I want to exclude those, would I have to remove them first?
- Some lines have missing values (`NaN`) that should be ignored.

I am not really sure, if what I want is possible but it would revolutionize my data analysis, so any input would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove any row with missing values:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Then, keep only integer numbers by comparing the column with its converted values as integer:

```
df = df[df.solenoid_valves == df.solenoid_valves.astype(int)]
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked fine....I m still trying to find a way though to insert an ID column that would change everytime the valve changes...I thought about using something like `grouped = df['solenoid_valves'].groupby(lambda x: x.hour)` but than a different group is created when the hour changes, but the valve has not changed yet....

Comment: (df.solenoid_valves!=df.solenoid_valves.shift()).cumsum()